# Node red editableList

Tags: node-red

Hello I'm creating my own nodes with node-red ... well I'm trying. I would like to create a special list with the following markup:

```html
-header
  key:value
  key:value
  key:value
-header
  key:value
  key:value
  key:value
-header
  key:value
  key:value
  key:value
-header
  key:value
  key:value
  key:value
```

I`m trying to use the editable list widget (https://nodered.org/docs/api/ui/editableList/) but I am missing a basic example so I can try and play around....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more detail about what you are trying to do here, because it really isn't clear

Comment: The question is if somebody has a simple example how to use this widget for node-red :  editable list widget (https://nodered.org/docs/api/ui/editableList/)

Comment: Have you looked at the change and switch node listed at top of the doc you point to? Those are the only examples

Answer (score 0):

you can check the node red example code like @hardillb mentioned above in comments.

This is the change code

```
<script type="text/html" data-template-name="change">
    <style>
        ol#node-input-rule-container .red-ui-typedInput-container {
            flex:1;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-name"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <span data-i18n="common.label.name"></span></label>
        <input type="text" id="node-input-name" data-i18n="[placeholder]common.label.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row" style="margin-bottom:0;">
        <label><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span data-i18n="change.label.rules"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row node-input-rule-container-row">
        <ol id="node-input-rule-container"></ol>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('change', {
        color: "#E2D96E",
        category: 'function',
        defaults: {
            name: {value:""},
            rules:{value:[{t:"set",p:"payload",pt:"msg",to:"",tot:"str"}]},
            // legacy
            action: {value:""},
            property: {value:""},
            from: {value:""},
            to: {value:""},
            reg: {value:false}
        },
        inputs: 1,
        outputs: 1,
        icon: "swap.svg",
        label: function() {
            function prop2name(type, key) {
                var result = RED.utils.parseContextKey(key);
                return type +"." +result.key;
            }
            if (this.name) {
                return this.name;
            }
            if (!this.rules) {
                if (this.action === "replace") {
                    return this._("change.label.set",{property:"msg."+this.property});
                } else if (this.action === "change") {
                    return this._("change.label.change",{property:"msg."+this.property});
                } else if (this.action === "move") {
                    return this._("change.label.move",{property:"msg."+this.property});
                } else {
                    return this._("change.label.delete",{property:"msg."+this.property});
                }
            } else {
                if (this.rules.length == 1) {
                    if (this.rules[0].t === "set") {
                        return this._("change.label.set",{property:prop2name((this.rules[0].pt||"msg"), this.rules[0].p)});
                    } else if (this.rules[0].t === "change") {
                        return this._("change.label.change",{property:prop2name((this.rules[0].pt||"msg"), this.rules[0].p)});
                    } else if (this.rules[0].t === "move") {
                        return this._("change.label.move",{property:prop2name((this.rules[0].pt||"msg"), this.rules[0].p)});
                    } else {
                        return this._("change.label.delete",{property:prop2name((this.rules[0].pt||"msg"), this.rules[0].p)});
                    }
                } else {
                    return this._("change.label.changeCount",{count:this.rules.length});
                }
            }
        },
        labelStyle: function() {
            return this.name ? "node_label_italic" : "";
        },
        oneditprepare: function() {
            var set = this._("change.action.set");
            var change = this._("change.action.change");
            var del = this._("change.action.delete");
            var move = this._("change.action.move");
            var to = this._("change.action.to");
            var search = this._("change.action.search");
            var replace = this._("change.action.replace");
            var regex = this._("change.label.regex");

            $('#node-input-rule-container').css('min-height','150px').css('min-width','450px').editableList({
                addItem: function(container,i,opt) {
                    var rule = opt;
                    if (!rule.hasOwnProperty('t')) {
                        rule = {t:"set",p:"payload",to:"",tot:"str"};
                    }
                    if (rule.t === "change" && rule.re) {
                        rule.fromt = 're';
                        delete rule.re;
                    }
                    if (rule.t === "set" && !rule.tot) {
                        if (rule.to.indexOf("msg.") === 0 && !rule.tot) {
                            rule.to = rule.to.substring(4);
                            rule.tot = "msg";
                        } else {
                            rule.tot = "str";
                        }
                    }
                    if (rule.t === "move" && !rule.tot) {
                        rule.tot = "msg";
                    }
                    container.css({
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
                    });
                    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                    var row1 = $('<div/>',{style:"display:flex;"}).appendTo(fragment);
                    var row2 = $('<div/>',{style:"display:flex;margin-top:8px;"}).appendTo(fragment);
                    var row3 = $('<div/>',{style:"margin-top:8px;"}).appendTo(fragment);
                    var row4 = $('<div/>',{style:"display:flex;margin-top:8px;"}).appendTo(fragment);

                    var selectField = $('<select/>',{class:"node-input-rule-type",style:"width:110px; margin-right:10px;"}).appendTo(row1);
                    var selectOptions = [{v:"set",l:set},{v:"change",l:change},{v:"delete",l:del},{v:"move",l:move}];
                    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
                        selectField.append($("<option></option>").val(selectOptions[i].v).text(selectOptions[i].l));
                    }

                    var propertyName = $('<input/>',{class:"node-input-rule-property-name",type:"text"})
                        .appendTo(row1)
                        .typedInput({types:['msg','flow','global']});

                    $('<div/>',{style:"display:inline-block;text-align:right; width:120px; padding-right:10px; box-sizing:border-box;"})
                        .text(to)
                        .appendTo(row2);

                    function createPropertyValue() {
                        return $('<input/>',{class:"node-input-rule-property-value",type:"text"})
                        .appendTo(row2)
                        .typedInput({default:'str',types:['msg','flow','global','str','num','bool','json','bin','date','jsonata','env']});
                    }

                    var row3_1 = $('<div/>', {style:"display:flex;"}).appendTo(row3);
                    $('<div/>',{style:"display:inline-block;text-align:right; width:120px; padding-right:10px; box-sizing:border-box;"})
                        .text(search)
                        .appendTo(row3_1);

                    function createFromValue() {
                        return $('<input/>',{class:"node-input-rule-property-search-value",type:"text"})
                        .appendTo(row3_1)
                        .typedInput({default:'str',types:['msg','flow','global','str','re','num','bool','env']});
                    }

                    var row3_2 = $('<div/>',{style:"display:flex;margin-top:8px;"}).appendTo(row3);
                    $('<div/>',{style:"display:inline-block;text-align:right; width:120px; padding-right:10px; box-sizing:border-box;"})
                        .text(replace)
                        .appendTo(row3_2);

                    function createToValue() {
                        return $('<input/>',{class:"node-input-rule-property-replace-value",type:"text"})
                        .appendTo(row3_2)
                        .typedInput({default:'str',types:['msg','flow','global','str','num','bool','json','bin','env']});
                    }

                    $('<div/>',{style:"display:inline-block;text-align:right; width:120px; padding-right:10px; box-sizing:border-box;"})
                        .text(to)
                        .appendTo(row4);

                    function createMoveValue() {
                        return $('<input/>',{class:"node-input-rule-property-move-value",type:"text"})
                        .appendTo(row4)
                        .typedInput({default:'msg',types:['msg','flow','global']});
                    }

                    let propertyValue = null;
                    let fromValue = null;
                    let toValue = null;
                    let moveValue = null;

                    selectField.on("change", function() {
                        var type = $(this).val();
                        if (propertyValue) {
                            propertyValue.typedInput('hide');
                        }
                        if (fromValue) {
                            fromValue.typedInput('hide');
                        }
                        if (toValue) {
                            toValue.typedInput('hide');
                        }
                        if (moveValue) {
                            moveValue.typedInput('hide');
                        }

                        if (type == "set") {
                            if(!propertyValue) {
                                propertyValue = createPropertyValue();
                            }
                            propertyValue.typedInput('show');
                            row2.show();
                            row3.hide();
                            row4.hide();
                        } else if (type == "change") {
                            if(!fromValue) {
                                fromValue = createFromValue();
                            }
                            fromValue.typedInput('show');
                            if(!toValue) {
                                toValue = createToValue();
                            }
                            toValue.typedInput('show');
                            row2.hide();
                            row3.show();
                            row4.hide();
                        } else if (type == "delete") {
                            row2.hide();
                            row3.hide();
                            row4.hide();
                        } else if (type == "move") {
                            if(!moveValue) {
                                moveValue = createMoveValue();
                            }
                            moveValue.typedInput('show');
                            row2.hide();
                            row3.hide();
                            row4.show();
                        }
                    });

                    selectField.val(rule.t);
                    propertyName.typedInput('value',rule.p);
                    propertyName.typedInput('type',rule.pt);
                    if (rule.t == "set") {
                        if(!propertyValue) {
                            propertyValue = createPropertyValue();
                        }
                        propertyValue.typedInput('value',rule.to);
                        propertyValue.typedInput('type',rule.tot);
                    }
                    if (rule.t == "move") {
                        if(!moveValue) {
                            moveValue = createMoveValue();
                        }
                        moveValue.typedInput('value',rule.to);
                        moveValue.typedInput('type',rule.tot);
                    }
                    if (rule.t == "change") {
                        if(!fromValue) {
                            fromValue = createFromValue();
                        }
                        fromValue.typedInput('value',rule.from);
                        fromValue.typedInput('type',rule.fromt);
                        if (!toValue) {
                            toValue = createToValue();
                        }
                        toValue.typedInput('value',rule.to);
                        toValue.typedInput('type',rule.tot);
                    }
                    selectField.change();
                    container[0].appendChild(fragment);
                },
                removable: true,
                sortable: true
            });

            if (!this.rules) {
                var rule = {
                    t:(this.action=="replace"?"set":this.action),
                    p:this.property,
                    pt:"msg"
                };

                if ((rule.t === "set")||(rule.t === "move")) {
                    rule.to = this.to;
                } else if (rule.t === "change") {
                    rule.from = this.from;
                    rule.to = this.to;
                    rule.re = this.reg;
                }

                delete this.to;
                delete this.from;
                delete this.reg;
                delete this.action;
                delete this.property;

                this.rules = [rule];
            }

            for (var i=0; i<this.rules.length; i++) {
                var rule = this.rules[i];
                $("#node-input-rule-container").editableList('addItem',rule);
            }
        },
        oneditsave: function() {
            var rules = $("#node-input-rule-container").editableList('items');
            var node = this;
            node.rules= [];
            rules.each(function(i) {
                var rule = $(this);
                var type = rule.find(".node-input-rule-type").val();
                var r = {
                    t:type,
                    p:rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-name").typedInput('value'),
                    pt:rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-name").typedInput('type')
                };
                if (type === "set") {
                    r.to = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-value").typedInput('value');
                    r.tot = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-value").typedInput('type');
                } else if (type === "move") {
                    r.to = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-move-value").typedInput('value');
                    r.tot = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-move-value").typedInput('type');
                } else if (type === "change") {
                    r.from = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-search-value").typedInput('value');
                    r.fromt = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-search-value").typedInput('type');
                    r.to = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-replace-value").typedInput('value');
                    r.tot = rule.find(".node-input-rule-property-replace-value").typedInput('type');
                }
                node.rules.push(r);
            });
        },
        oneditresize: function(size) {
            var rows = $("#dialog-form>div:not(.node-input-rule-container-row)");
            var height = size.height;
            for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
                height -= $(rows[i]).outerHeight(true);
            }
            var editorRow = $("#dialog-form>div.node-input-rule-container-row");
            height -= (parseInt(editorRow.css("marginTop"))+parseInt(editorRow.css("marginBottom")));
            height += 16;
            $("#node-input-rule-container").editableList('height',height);
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can find the same here at
https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/nodes/core/function/15-change.html